# Simple Application of Leibniz Integral Rule

Tags: differential-geometry

Let the volume of a convex polyhedron be given by:
$$ \int_{v(\lambda)} f(x) dx $$
What is the expression for the derivative of the volume of the convex polyhedron with respect to $\lambda$?

I've found some slightly more general questions (e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/300332/rigorous-multivariate-differentiation-of-integral-with-moving-boundaries-leibni?newreg=43da0240bd7244efaf254b95985c0403) but I am having trouble understanding the answers and applying them to my case. I've never studied differential geometry, so I am a bit out of my depth. I hope you don't mind that I am asking this similar, but simpler question.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What is $v(\lambda)$?

Comment: Sorry. v(\lambda) is the bounds of integration which are a function of \lambda. In my particular application, it's a linear function. Does that make sense?

Comment: Could you give an explicit example of $\nu(\lambda)$? Do you mean that for each $\lambda$, $\nu(\lambda)$ represents a convex polyhedron?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a time varying region $\Omega(t)$ defined by diffeomorphisms $\phi(t, \cdot) : \Omega_0 \to \Omega(t)$ from a reference region $\Omega_0$. Then via a computation (either [directly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_transport_theorem#Form_for_a_material_element), or using differential forms and the lie derivative), we obtain
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\Omega(t)}f(x)\,dx = \int_{\partial \Omega(t)}f(x)\phi_t(t, x) \cdot N(x)\,dS(x).$$
Here $\phi_t(t, x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\phi(t, x)$, $N(x)$ is the outward normal vector, and $dS$ is the surface measure on $\partial \Omega(t)$. You can use this result to compute $\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda_j} \int_{v(\lambda)}f(x)\,dx$.

Comment: Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I also found ["Derivative of an integral over a convex polytope"](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aml.2011.01.037) by C. Müller, A. Feuer and G.C. Goodwin ("Applied Mathematics Letters", Volume 24, Issue 7, 2011, Pages 1120-1123) very helpful: I believe theorem 1 answers exactly the question I posed.